# Obj-C, top centering a label on a view /

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I'm having some trouble positioning a label at the top of a view, so that it's centred. However, as I'm using dates the width of the string varies. I've also noticed that on 3.5 inch screens, the text doesn't fit. I've also got two image buttons on either side of the label.

So I need to have a margin.

To further complicate matters, the view is only show in landscape, so the left is top etc.

```
ViewController *nextController = [[ViewController alloc] 
              initWithNibName:@"View" bundle:nil];
CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformMake(0.0,1.0,-1.0,0.0,0.0,0.0);         
nextController.view.transform = newTransform;
nextController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
```

I did think all I would need to do was...

```
int margin = 50;
lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(margin, 2, th - (margin * 2), 22);
```

But that doesn't work.
It's almost like it's adding the height of the status bar on the left, but the status bar is visible. I've had numerous attempts, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
lblTitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
lblTitle.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - from %@ to %@", 
                       strChartType, displayStartDate, displayEndDate];

int th = self.view.frame.size.height;
//int th = self.view.bounds.size.height;

lblTitle.frame = CGRectMake(0, 2, th, 22);  // x, y, w, h

//[lblTitle setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | 
           UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin];

//lblTitle.center = CGPointMake( self.view.bounds.size.width / 2, 10);

[lblTitle setTextAlignment:UITextAlignmentCenter];
lblTitle.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:14];
lblTitle.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = FALSE;

lblTitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

[self.view addSubview:lblTitle];
```

Comment: `CGRectGetMidX()` and `CGRectGetMidY()` and should be helpful

Comment: What is th evaluating to, and what do you think it should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could get the screen bounds and then subtract the height of the status bar to get the label width.

```
float screenHeight = [UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.height;
float statusBarHeight = ([UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height < [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width) ? [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.height : [UIApplication sharedApplication].statusBarFrame.size.width;
float labelWidth = screenHeight - statusBarHeight;
```

Note: mainScreen bounds always returns in portrait mode so you don't have to worry about orientation, but statusBarFrame can be rotated so you need to check if the width or height of the frame is the correct value to use.

Comment: Hi @Joel, I took off 100 from width and this produced the same as the image above. In effect the same result as I produced.

Comment: If you don't subtract 100, does it go from the top to the bottom as expected? Something else is going on. You need to log all the frame sizes (view, label, etc) and see which one is producing the unexpected result.

Comment: Was it going exactly to the bottom, or past the bottom? subtract a couple pixels to see if it was going to the bottom exactly (if you subtract 2, you should see the space).

Comment: I made a mistake earlier, it works with your code now, thanks :)